Prove $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \frac{(2k-1)^{2j}}{2^{2nj+n-1}}=\frac{1}{2j+1}, \forall j \in \mathbb{R}, j > -\frac{1}{2}$
For background, I was attempting to show the following without the use of typical trigonometric identities, as I found it to be a bit of a cop out:
$$S_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \cos\left(\frac{x}{2^k}\right), \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
My general process was this:
\begin{align}
    S_n &= \cos \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)\cos \left( \frac{x}{4} \right)\cdots\cos \left( \frac{x}{2^n} \right) \\\\
    &=\left(\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{2}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{4}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{4}}}{2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{e^{\frac{ix}{2^n}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{2^n}}}{2}\right) \\\\
    &=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{ix}{2}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{2}}\right)\left(e^{\frac{ix}{4}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{4}}\right)\cdots\left(e^{\frac{ix}{2^n}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{2^n}}\right)}{2^n}\\\\
    &=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{ix}{2^n}} + e^{-\frac{ix}{2^n}}\right) + \left(e^{\frac{3ix}{2^n}} + e^{-\frac{3ix}{2^n}}\right) + \cdots + \left(e^{\frac{(2^n-1)ix}{2^n}} + e^{\frac{-(2^n-1)ix}{2^n}}\right)}{2^n}\\\\
    &=\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\left(\frac{e^{\frac{\left(2k-1\right)ix}{2^{n}}}+e^{-\frac{\left(2k-1\right)ix}{2^{n}}}}{2^{n}}\right) \\\\
    &=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\cos\left(\frac{\left(2k-1\right)x}{2^{n}}\right) \\\\
    &=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}\left(\frac{\left(2k-1\right)x}{2^{n}}\right)^{2j}}{\left(2j\right)!}
\end{align}
Which got me from a product of cosines to a sum of cosines. I'm fairly certain that I can apply Fubini's Theorem for Series' here, as:
$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}\left(\frac{\left(2k-1\right)x}{2^{n}}\right)^{2j}}{\left(2j\right)!}\right| = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac{\left(2k-1\right)x}{2^{n}}\right)^{2j}}{\left(2j\right)!}$$
Though I have not gone the extra step to rigorously prove the prior series' convergence, it intuitively seems as if it should converge (the factorial term should dominate the exponential), and I apologize if I am mistaken.
But then using Fubini's Theorem for Series':
\begin{align}
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}x^{2j}\left(2k-1\right)^{2j}}{\left(2j\right)!2^{2nj+n-1}}\right) \\\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}x^{2j}}{\left(2j\right)!}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\frac{\left(2k-1\right)^{2j}}{2^{2nj+n-1}}
\end{align}
This is the point at which I am stuck.
The series expansion for $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ (using analogous variables) is:
$$\begin{equation}
    \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}x^{2j}}{\left(2j+1\right)!}
\end{equation}$$
Thus, if:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}S_n = \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \implies \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}x^{2j}}{\left(2j\right)!}\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}}\frac{\left(2k-1\right)^{2j}}{2^{2nj+n-1}} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{j}x^{2j}}{\left(2j+1\right)!}$$
Which then leads to the conclusion that:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \frac{(2k-1)^{2j}}{2^{2nj+n-1}} = \frac{1}{2j+1}, \forall j \in \mathbb{R}, j > -\frac{1}{2}$$
Or in other words, that the series converges to the positive half of $\frac{1}{2j+1}$ as $n$ tends to infinity.
I made an effort to show this equivalence through the $\frac{1}{1-x}$ substitution for the right side, but immediately realized that the radius of convergence would prevent this from holding for all nonnegative integer $j$ (the only $j$ under consideration for the series).
Applying the limit to the integral approximation of the finite series gives me:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{(2^n - 1)^{2j} \cdot 2^n - ((2^n - 1)^{2j} - 1)}{(4j + 2)\left(2^{2jn+n-1}\right)}$$
Which does in fact equal $\frac{1}{2j + 1}, \forall j > 0$, but it leaves me feeling deeply unsatisfied.
I then ask for an alternative method of evaluation (if there is one), or perhaps a more rigorous approach toward the integral approximation above. I once again apologize for any computational or logical errors, and ask for corrections in that case, as the work above is simply scratch-work for a more formal proof.

Define the real number $a:=2j>-1$. More generally, applying the general result about Riemann sums to the pointed partition $x_k:=\frac kN,x_k^*:=\frac{k-\frac12}N$ of $[0,1]$:
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac1N\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\frac{k-\frac12}N\right)^a=\int_0^1x^a\,dx=\frac1{a+1}$$
Your statement corresponds to the subsequence indexed by $n$ such that $N=2^{n-1}$.

Playing with the zeta functions
$$S_j(n)= \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} \frac{(2k-1)^{2j}}{2^{2nj+n-1}}=-2^{-2 j n-n+1} \left(4^j \,\zeta \left(-2j,\frac{2^n+1}{2} \right)+\left(4^j-1\right)
   \zeta (-2 j)\right)$$
If $j$ is an integer
$$S_j(n)=-2^{-(2 j+1) (n-1)}\,\,\zeta \left(-2 j,\frac{2^n+1}{2} \right)$$
Have a look at $25.11.43$ in $DLMF$ for the asymptotics of  the Hurwitz zeta function .
It works the same for non integer values of $j$.

For any integer $m$, consider the partition $\mathcal{P}_m$ of the interval $[0,1]$ in $m$ pieces of same length, that is
$\mathcal{P}_m=\left\{\frac{k-1}{m}:1\leq k\leq m+1\right\}$. If $f$ is Riemann integrable (for example continuous) over $[0,1]$ then for any tag $x^*_k\in\left[\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}\right]$ the Riemann sum
$$\frac1m\sum^{m}_{k=1}f(x^*_j)\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0f(x)\,dx$$
In particular, if one takes $x^*_k$ asthe mid-point of $\left[\frac{k-1}{m},\frac{k}{m}\right]$, one obtains
$$\frac1m\sum^{m}_{k=1}f\left(\frac{2k-1}{2m}\right)\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0f(x)\,dx\tag{1}\label{one}$$
For $f(x)=x^{2j}$, $2j\neq-1$, the limit \eqref{one} takes the form
$$\frac1m\sum^m_{k=1}\Big(\frac{2k-1}{2m}\Big)^{2j}\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0 x^{2j}\,dx=\frac{1}{2j+1}$$
In the OP, $m\rightarrow\infty$ along the subsequence $m_n=2^{n}$. (The result holds also for $2j<-1$ since $f$ is monotone).

Comment:

There is also a probabilistic argument for the $$\prod^\infty_{k=1}\cos\Big(\frac{x}{2^k}\Big)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$
Suppose $(X_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ is an i.i.d sequence of Bernoulli random variable with $\mathbb{P}[X_1=\pm1]=\frac12$. The sum
$$S_n=\sum^{n}_{k=1}2^{-k}X_k=\sum^\infty_{k=1}2^{-k}X_k$$
converges (absolutely) to another random variable $U$. Once can argue that $U$ is the uniform distribution over $(-1,1)$ ($S_n$ has uniform distribution over dyadic numbers in $(-1,1)$ with denominator $2^n$).
Observer that the characteristic function of $S_n$ is
$$\mathbb{E}\Big[e^{ix\sum^n_{k=1}2^{-k}X_k}\Big]=\prod^n_{k=1}\mathbb{E}[e^{ix2^{-k}X_k}]=\prod^n_{k=1}\cos\Big(\frac{x}{2^k}\Big)
$$
The characteristic function of the uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$ is
$$\frac12\int^1_{-1}e^{ixt}\,dt=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

